# Binding more properties into GridViewColumnHeader

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I would like to make GridView with column header, for example like exampe below (example for one column). My DataTemplate for header contains have more controls (TextBlock and TextBox) and I am not able to figure out how to set binding to access individual controls from template (header). In my example, instead of "aaa" to set value of HColumn1Line2 property.

```
<ListView Name="PeopleList" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">

    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyHeaderTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBox Text="aaa"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView ColumnHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}">
            <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding HColumn1Line1}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PeopleListItem}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>

</ListView>
```

//Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PeopleList.DataContext = this;
        _people.Add(new Person() { PeopleListItem = "some information" });

        HColumn1Line1 = "Header line #1";
        HColumn1Line2 = "text instead of aaa";
    }

    public List<Person> People { get { return _people; } }
    List<Person> _people = new List<Person>();

    public string HColumn1Line1 { get; set; }
    public string HColumn1Line2 { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string PeopleListItem { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you have is you are using the `MainWindow` instance as `DataContext` for the `ListView` which is in the `MainWindow` `Content` this will run you into exceptions such as "Logical tree depth exceeded while traversing the tree.", so you better make your DataContext a seperate object such as the following:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PeopleList.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }

    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<Person> People { get { return _people; } }
        List<Person> _people = new List<Person>();

        public string HColumn1Line1 { get; set; } = "Header line #1";
        public string HColumn1Line2 { get; set; } = "text instead of aaa";

        public ViewModel()
        {

            _people.Add(new Person() { PeopleListItem = "some information" });
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string PeopleListItem { get; set; }
    }
```

Updated XAML:

```
<ListView Name="PeopleList" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">

        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MyHeaderTemplate">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HColumn1Line1}"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding HColumn1Line2}"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}">
                <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PeopleListItem}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>
```